# LaTeX file getting information from 2 other files

Tags: positioning, koma-script, invoice

I just downloaded it to automate writing bills. I have absolutely zero knowledge of the terminology. Only a bit knowledge of scripting.

Here is the link to the repository:
https://github.com/d-koppenhagen/latex-rechnung

But the thing I do not like about it is, that the `_main.tex` is getting information from 2 other files. The `_data.tex` and `_invoice.tex`.
Is there a way to make the `_main.tex` only get the information from one file?
Since when I need to write a bill it is much more convenient to edit one file instead of two.

And how do I increase the space of the red rectangle? So that the end of the IBAN would be more to the left.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move your header to the left (to get more space in your marked red rectangle) change in file `_main.tex`  the code

```
\setkomavar{firsthead}{\hfill
   \parbox[t][\headheight][t]{6cm}{%
```

to

```
\setkomavar{firsthead}{\hfill
   \parbox[t][\headheight][t]{7cm}{% <================================== 6cm
```

Set `7cm` to a value you need ...

In file `_data-tex` are two relevant datas: the data of the writer of the invoice (I guess that data have to be rewriten only once for your own datas :-) and the data for the receipient:

```
% ################## invoice DATA ##################
\newcommand{\invoiceDate}{DD.MM.YYYY} % Datum der rechnungsstellung
\newcommand{\payDate}{DD.MM.YYYY} % Datum der Zahlungsfrist
\newcommand{\invoiceReference}{YYYYMMDD-1} % Rechnungsnummer (z.B. 20150122-4)
\newcommand{\invoiceSalutation}{Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,} % die Anrede
\newcommand{\invoiceText}{Für die von mir erbrachte Leistung erhalten sie
hiermit die Rechnung. Bitte zahlen Sie den unten aufgeführten Gesamtbetrag
unter Angabe der Rechnungsnummer (\invoiceReference) bis
zum \payDate \ auf das angegebene Konto ein.} % Rechnungstext
\newcommand{\invoiceEnclosures}{} % \encl{} einfügen
\newcommand{\invoiceClosing}{Mit freundlichen Grüßen}
% ################## invoice DATA ################## 

% ################## Customer DATA ##################
\newcommand{\customerCompany}{Firma XYZ} %ggf. Firma
\newcommand{\customerName}{Max Mustermann} % Name
\newcommand{\customerStreet}{Robert-Koch-Str. 12} % Straße
\newcommand{\customerZIP}{12345} % Postleitzahl
\newcommand{\customerCity}{Musterstadt} % Ort
% ################## Customer DATA ##################
```

You can **move** this code to `_main.tex` and then you have to change it in `_main.tex` for each new invoice.

So rename the original file `_data.tex` to `_data-original.tex` and use the new shorter file `_data.tex` containing only your datas:

```
% ################## Personal DATA ##################
% START INVOICE DATA
\newcommand{\taxID}{123/456/78901}
% END INVOICE DATA
% START SENDERS DATA
\newcommand{\senderName}{MeinVorname MeinNachname}
\newcommand{\senderStreet}{Meine-Str. 125}
\newcommand{\senderZIP}{67890}
\newcommand{\senderCity}{Musterstadt}
\newcommand{\senderTelephone}{+49 (0)33445 9876345}
\newcommand{\senderMobilephone}{+49 (0)151 29134704}
\newcommand{\senderEmail}{mail@domain.de}
\newcommand{\senderWeb}{\url{www.domain.com}}
% END SENDERES DATA
% START ACCOUNT DATA
\newcommand{\accountRCPT}{\senderName}
\newcommand{\accountNumber}{1234567890}
\newcommand{\accountBLZ}{30060088}
\newcommand{\accountBankName}{DAB-Bank}
\newcommand{\accountIBAN}{DE00 3006 0088 1234 5678 90}
\newcommand{\accountBIC}{DRTTZZUUXXX}
% END ACCOUNT DATA
% ################## Personal DATA ##################
```

In file `_invoice.tex` used in `_main.tex` with `\input{_invoice}` you have the content of the invoice you want to be paid for.  Copy the content of `_input.tex` and paste it in `_main.tex` instead of `\input{_invoice}`:

```
% koma_env.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=1cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage[german]{invoice}


\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

% include meta data
\include{_data} % <============== delete in this file the following data!
% ################## invoice DATA ##################
\newcommand{\invoiceDate}{DD.MM.YYYY} % Datum der rechnungsstellung
\newcommand{\payDate}{DD.MM.YYYY} % Datum der Zahlungsfrist
\newcommand{\invoiceReference}{YYYYMMDD-1} % Rechnungsnummer (z.B. 20150122-4)
\newcommand{\invoiceSalutation}{Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,} % die Anrede
\newcommand{\invoiceText}{Für die von mir erbrachte Leistung erhalten sie
hiermit die Rechnung. Bitte zahlen Sie den unten aufgeführten Gesamtbetrag
unter Angabe der Rechnungsnummer (\invoiceReference) bis
zum \payDate \ auf das angegebene Konto ein.} % Rechnungstext
\newcommand{\invoiceEnclosures}{} % \encl{} einfügen
\newcommand{\invoiceClosing}{Mit freundlichen Grüßen}
% ################## invoice DATA ##################

% ################## Customer DATA ##################
\newcommand{\customerCompany}{Firma XYZ} %ggf. Firma
\newcommand{\customerName}{Max Mustermann} % Name
\newcommand{\customerStreet}{Robert-Koch-Str. 12} % Straße
\newcommand{\customerZIP}{12345} % Postleitzahl
\newcommand{\customerCity}{Musterstadt} % Ort
% ################## Customer DATA ##################

\setkomavar{fromname}{\senderName}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{\senderStreet \\ \senderZIP \ \senderCity}
\setkomavar{place}{\senderCity}
\setkomavar{date}{\invoiceDate}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{\senderTelephone}
\setkomavar{frommobilephone}{\senderMobilephone}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{\href{mailto:\senderEmail}{\nolinkurl{\senderEmail}}}
\setkomavar{subject}{Rechnung}
\setkomavar{location}{
  \\[\baselineskip] \\[\baselineskip]
  \flushright \small {\vspace{1cm}Rechnungsnummer: 
  \invoiceReference}
}

\setkomavar{firsthead}{\hfill
   \parbox[t][\headheight][t]{7cm}{% <================================== 6cm
   \footnotesize
   \raggedright
   \flushright
   \color[gray]{.3}%
    \begin{tabular}{rl}
         Anschrift & \usekomavar{fromname}\\
         & \senderStreet\\
         & \senderZIP  \ \senderCity \\
         \\
         %\Telefon \ Telefon:  \` \senderTelephone \\
         Mobil  & \usekomavar{frommobilephone} \\
         E-Mail  & \usekomavar{fromemail} \\
         Webseite & {\normalfont\ttfamily  \senderWeb } \\
         \\
         Steuernummer & \taxID \\
         \\
         Institut & \accountBankName \\
         IBAN & \accountIBAN \\
         BIC & \accountBIC
    \end{tabular}                   
   }%
}


\begin{document}
    \begin{letter}{\customerCompany \\ \customerName \\ 
    \customerStreet \\ \customerZIP \ \customerCity}

            \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{logo.png}            
            \opening{\invoiceSalutation}
            \invoiceText
            \begin{invoice}{Euro}{0}
\ProjectTitle{Projekttitel} % <=========================================
\Fee{Musterdienstleistung 1}{30.00}{4}
\Fee{Musterdienstleistung 2}{36.00}{7}

% Auslagen
%\EBCi{Hotel, 12 Nächte} {2400.00}
%\STExpenses

% Rabatt
\Discount{Rabatt} {20} % <==============================================
            \end{invoice}
        \ps Im ausgewiesenen Betrag ist gemäß § 19 UStG keine Umsatzsteuer 
        enthalten.

        \closing{\invoiceClosing}
        \invoiceEnclosures



    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

with the resulting pdf:

[image]